# Breeze expand error

Tags: breeze

Not sure if this is possible using Breeze, but we have a situation where we need to return an `IQueryable` from 2 different sources.

Our business logic called from our controller action checks to see if some data is stored within a database, if so an `IQueryable` is returned from the repository which uses the `EFContextProvider`.

Otherwise, a `List<T>` is created containing default data and turned into an `IQueryable`, which is then returned.

On the client side, our query contains .expand to ensure the navigation properties are populated with the required data.

This works fine when the `IQueryable` is coming from the EF, but crashes with the following error when creating the `List<T>`:

```
{"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery<MyObject>' does not contain a definition for 'Include'","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException","StackTrace":"   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , String )\r\n   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass14.<ApplyExpand>b__11(String expand)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.ApplyExpand(IQueryable queryable, String expandsQueryString)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.QueryHelper.ApplySelectAndExpand(IQueryable queryable, NameValueCollection map)\r\n   at Breeze.WebApi.BreezeQueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"}
```

Is this an issue with Breeze (we're using 1.4.2 at present), or is it something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does the server side method look like?

Comment: Everything is deferred to our business logic layer, but the controller looks like: `[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<XXX> Customers(string id) {
  return logic.Get(id);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet in this case in this case is remove the 'expand' from the client and move it the server (as an Include).  Something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Customer> Customers(someCriteria) {
  if (... haveData ...) {
      return ContextProvider.Context.Customers.Include("Orders");
  } else {
      return DefaultCustomerList.AsQueryable()
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but just wondered if I was missing something obvious. Will give it try tomorrow.

Comment: Moving the expand to the server fixed my immediate issues. Did some testing with the WebApi2 version of Breeze and it seems to work fine from the client side using that version, but we can't upgrade to that version at present.